# How find specific time when vector changes

Tags: r, loops

I'm trying to get time of the day when the day_high changes (breakouts)

```
> df
                     Preco day_high day_low
2018-02-01 09:01:21 3203.5   3203.5    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:21 3203.5   3203.5    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:23 3204.5   3204.5    3202
```

That's what I tried:

```
library(lubridate)

for (i in 1:150) {
    if ((df$day_high[i] != df$day_high[i+1]) & (df$day_high[i] == df$day_high[i - minutes(1)])) {
        print(df[[i]][i])
    } else {
        next
    }
}
```

> ```
> > Error in if ((df$day_high[i] != df$day_high[i + 1]) & (df$day_high[i]
> > ==  :    argument is of length zero
> ```

That's what I'm looking for (the periods that `day_high` changes):

```
[1]
2018-02-01 09:01:22 3204.0   3204.0    3202
2018-02-01 09:01:23 3204.5   3204.5    3202
```

Code for reproduction:

```
df = structure(c(3203.5, 3203.5, 3204, 3204, 3204, 3204, 3204, 3204, 
3204, 3204, 3204.5, 3203.5, 3203.5, 3204, 3204, 3204, 3204, 3204, 
3204, 3204, 3204, 3204.5, 3202, 3202, 3202, 3202, 3202, 3202, 
3202, 3202, 3202, 3202, 3202), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", index = structure(c(1517482881, 
1517482881, 1517482882, 1517482882, 1517482882, 1517482882, 1517482882, 
1517482882, 1517482882, 1517482882, 1517482883), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(11L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("Preco", 
"day_high", "day_low")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `diff` and select the rows which is not same as its previous row.

```
df[diff(df$day_high) != 0, ]

#                    Preco day_high day_low
#2018-02-01 19:01:22  3204     3204    3202
#2018-02-01 19:01:23  3204.5   3204.5  3202
```

Comment: Can you make this a bit shorter please? Maybe a 0-liner?

Comment: I guess `df[!!diff(df$day_high),]` is a little shorter. Not quite a 0-liner though @thelatemail

Comment: @dww - I won't be happy until we're down to nothing but non-printing characters.